# sklearn ensure features ordered as expected for predict

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I train a model using sklearn, trained on data in a pandas dataframe. See below for a code snippet that can reproduce the model that I train.

```py
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
dataset = load_iris()

X = pd.DataFrame(dataset['data'], columns=dataset['feature_names'])
y = pd.DataFrame(dataset['target'], columns=['target_names'])
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
logistic_regression = LogisticRegression()
logistic_regression.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Now, when I want to make predictions, a user sends the predictions via a dictionary, where each key is the feature name and each value is the value for that feature.

There seems to be no enforcement that features in the predict are named as per the features in the DataFrame. I understand this, but the question is, when the features are named by the user, how can I know how they are ordered?

```
example = {
 'a':1, # randomly named features 
 'b':2,
 'c':3,
 'd':4
}
logistic_regression.predict(pd.DataFrame.from_records(example, index=[0]))  # works
```

How do I know if the predict sent these values as `[1,2,3,4]` or `[2,1,3,4]` etc.

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly you need some kind of mapping (user features to model features) or force the user to send features in the correct order. Otherwise there is no way (at least non hackish/task dependent ones).

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is to store the order `feature_names` of the training data, so that when new data comes in as a dictionary, you can use that stored order to sort the values.

The other way if you don't want to store extra object is to add some kind of "order identifier" in your dictionary keys. For example, if say the order is `d b c a`, then you can change the name of the dictionary key as `1_d`, `2_b`, `3_c`, `4_a`, so that if you convert it to list, you have a way of sorting it without using the original feature list.